# How to make a formula with changing variables in excel?

Tags: excel

Okay so if I had an equation x=cos(t), The value of t changes from 1-20 and is located A1:A20 respectively. how can I insert a function in which the value of t is substituted in each time. For example at A12 (where t equals 12) the x equation would become 'cos(12)' (this information would be located in the column beside.

I know I can type In "=Cos(A1)", "=cos(A2)", "=cos(A3)" and so on but my issue is that I need this to work for ANY excel equation that is typed in AND I need it to be abled to transfer from one sheet to another . For example if x were to equal: t, t^4, sin(t), cos(t) + t^2.

Is there any equation which would work as follows:

=cos(t)+t^2 <- the equation someone typed for x

This information is then moved to a background spreadsheet and becomes

=cos(t)+t^2,(t=RC[-1])

Am I missing something? is this possible?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% what you are asking for, but you can certainly enter formulas ina way that looks more like straight math rather than Excel syntax. You can define a workbook name to refer to the cell which is to the left of a given cell. I don't like using `t` for this since there is a worksheet function `T()`, but `x` is a good choice.

While `B1` is selected use the `Define Name` option on the formula ribbon and enter the name `x` and the refers to as `=A1`:

[image]

It is important that the formula isn't something like `Sheet1!$A$1`.

Then -- anywhere else in the workbook you can use formulas like this:

[image]

Which can be copied down the range of cells instantly by just double-clicking the lower right hand corner of the cell containing the formula.